# Hi , what should a man do if he impregnates a woman before wedlock ? should he marry her or opt for co-parenting?

Tags: sexuality, mussar-ethics

Lets say the child is already born , you are both not married, you are friends , you used to date but you had broken up. What should these two do ?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a halachic requirement to choose one option in particular?

Comment: This isn't the sort of question one can answer based on a website. See the box in the top right corner.

Comment: Do they want to get married?

Comment: This question asking for a personal ruling isn't within the scope of this website (that's a question that should be posed to a local Orthodox rabbi) but just for reference the gemarra has examples of both.

Comment: @JoshK how is it personal?

Comment: How do you know the yichud that produced the child didn't constitute a marriage?

Answer (score 1):

While we'd *generally* consider it better for a child to be raised with married parents, that's assuming the marriage is a healthy one. Otherwise you're not doing anyone any favors.

(We do have records of a pregnant woman demanding support from an alleged biological father, but that's a bit different. Here, fortunately, everyone agrees to the facts.)

The closest analogy in *halacha*, arguably, would be a case of levirate marriage. A fellow gets a phone call that his brother died without children. (Let's simplify and assume the fellow is Sephardic.) He has two options: A.) Marry the widow. B.) Go through a ritual in which he publicly pronounces before the rabbis that he refuses to marry her, a few other ceremonies are performed, and then she can go marry someone else.

While A is preferable, the Talmud says the rabbis should meet with the couple and determine if they seem compatible. If so, they advise A. If not, they advise B.

I'd assume the same applies -- if the couple feels they can make it work, and they've consulted with a relationship expert who agrees, then that's the right move. But if it's just going to be a disaster, they wouldn't be doing anyone any favors.

Comment: Why is that the closest analogy in *halacha*? What about וְנָתַן הָאִישׁ הַשֹּׁכֵב עִמָּהּ לַאֲבִי הַנַּעֲרָה חֲמִשִּׁים כָּסֶף וְלוֹ תִהְיֶה לְאִשָּׁה תַּחַת אֲשֶׁר עִנָּהּ לֹא יוּכַל שַׁלְּחָהּ כָּל יָמָיו.?

Comment: @pcoz That's rape, you probably mean וְכִי-יְפַתֶּה אִישׁ, בְּתוּלָה אֲשֶׁר לֹא-אֹרָשָׂה--וְשָׁכַב עִמָּהּ:  מָהֹר יִמְהָרֶנָּה לּוֹ, לְאִשָּׁה

Comment: @pcoz Deuteronomy 22:29 refers to a case of rape. In this case, the relations were consensual.

Comment: @IsraelReader Yes, sorry, as per DoubleAA.

Comment: @pcoz thanks, though that doesn't apply once she's an adult (it's a penalty for taking advantage of her youth). Hence my example of yibbum, grownups (well ... at least not *her* first rodeo) being asked "hm does this look workable."

Comment: @Shalom I meant from a conceptual perspective. I.e. it is the moral responsibility of the man to take this woman under his wing.

Comment: @pcoz that is, again, she's young and vulnerable without a husband. Have to find other cases in halacha about grownups. Igros has a solid FFB girl who moved into a college dorm and oops found herself involved with a Jewish boy. RMF writes "if the boy wants to marry you, the ksubah should still say *besulah*" He does not indicate any pressure. R' Oppenheimer of Buenos Aires had a Jewish guy whose got his girlfriend pregnant after she'd started studying for conversion. R' Moshe allows the rabbi to convert her and marry them as it's far less chilul Hashem than her suing for support.